# declare function and return varchar oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to declare a function in pl/sql and return a variable content from it.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION executeTransaction
    RETURN VARCHAR2 as
    pragma autonomous_transaction;
    myLog VARCHAR(1200) :='myLog';
  BEGIN
    savepoint my_savepoint;
    begin
        insert into datalogger(MPRN_FK,K0213,K0214) values(465,'2142342','423423');
        myLog := 'transaction completed with rows insert ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT;
        rollback to my_savepoint;
    end;
    insert into myTbl(col) values(myLog);
    RETURN myLog;
  END executeTransaction;
```

The function compiles but when I execute it like

```
select executeTransaction from dual;
```

I am getting

```
ORA-06519: active autonomous transaction detected and rolled back
ORA-06512: at "ECO_AFMS_GAS_CUST.GET_ALLITEMS", line 14
06519. 00000 -  "active autonomous transaction detected and rolled back"
*Cause:    Before returning from an autonomous PL/SQL block, all autonomous
           transactions started within the block must be completed (either
           committed or rolled back). If not, the active autonomous
           transaction is implicitly rolled back and this error is raised.
*Action:   Ensure that before returning from an autonomous PL/SQL block,
           any active autonomous transactions are explicitly committed
           or rolled back.
```

and the variable content is not returned? I know that I must either commit or rollback but in this case I rollback so it should work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using [pragma autonomous_transaction](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems002.htm), you need to add `COMMIT` at the end of your function. As the error states

> If not, the active autonomous transaction is implicitly rolled back and this error is raised.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION executeTransaction
    RETURN VARCHAR2 as
    pragma autonomous_transaction;
    myLog VARCHAR(1200) :='myLog';
  BEGIN
    savepoint my_savepoint;
    begin
        insert into datalogger(MPRN_FK,K0213,K0214) values(465,'2142342','423423');
        myLog := 'transaction completed with rows insert ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT;
        rollback to my_savepoint;
    end;
    insert into myTbl(col) values(myLog);
    commit;         --add commit
    RETURN myLog;
  END executeTransaction;
```